# Exit Values in Eclipse using C - What do they mean?

Tags: mysql, c, eclipse

I have a short program written to try to connect to a MySQL database.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main () {
    MYSQL *conn;
    char *server = "localhost";
    char *user = "root";
    char *password = "";
    char *database = "database";
    int port = 3306;
    conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    mysql_real_connect(conn, server,user,password,database, port, NULL, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

It builds fine, but when I run it, the console reads

```
<terminated> (exit value: -1,073,741,515)
```

I don't think that is good, but I also have no idea what it means.  Can anybody help me to decipher this?

Comment: What if you run the executable in a command shell?

Comment: See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30550496/eclipse-c-c-terminated-exit-value-1073741515#comment49181071_30550496)

Comment: Will "hello world" program run on this setup?

Comment: "Hello World" runs just fine.  So I believe it must have to do with linking the correct libraries and the mysql code.  The program build with no errors, but won't execute.  The problem is, I have no idea how to decipher this error, I don't even know where to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

This program worked for me against a fresh mysql 5.7 install with Ubuntu Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
int main() {
    MYSQL *conn;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    char *server = "localhost";
    char *user = "root";
    char *password = "<passwrd>"; /* set me first */
    char *database = "mysql";
    conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    /* Connect to database */
    if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
                            user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }

    /* send SQL query */
    if (mysql_query(conn, "show tables")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }
    res = mysql_use_result(conn);

    /* output table name */
    printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
        printf("%s \n", row[0]);

    /* close connection */
    mysql_free_result(res);
    mysql_close(conn);
}
```

Test

```
 ./a.out 
MySQL Tables in mysql database:
columns_priv 
db 
engine_cost 
event 
func 
general_log 
gtid_executed 
help_category 
help_keyword 
help_relation 
help_topic 
innodb_index_stats 
innodb_table_stats 
ndb_binlog_index 
plugin 
proc 
procs_priv 
proxies_priv 
server_cost 
servers 
slave_master_info 
slave_relay_log_info 
slave_worker_info 
slow_log 
tables_priv 
time_zone 
time_zone_leap_second 
time_zone_name 
time_zone_transition 
time_zone_transition_type 
user
```

Please check that your mysql is running and accepting connections and that the program terminates properly. It might be easier to use the command-line to link your `mysql.h` (I did it with `gcc main.c -lmysqlclient` when I compiled the above).

Comment: Thanks for running this example.  I am using Windows. I was not able to get anything to work at all trying to connect to MySQL using Eclipse with C.  I eventually switched to Pelles C.  At first I was running into similar problems, but read a post that said to include the libmysql.dll in the same folder with the executable file. When I did this, I finally had  success.  Crashed the program when I did it with Eclipse. I didn't read in any of the documentation where it told you what to do with the dynamic dll library.  At least I have something working at this point, but I wish it was Eclipse.

Comment: @sax If you program C, did you try Clion? I think Clion is a good IDE.